# how to resize the image to fit in UIImageview in a tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I am getting data from user such as Title, description, and a photo of a product and display it on posts page. I get the image, download url to firebase, then get it again with url session and here is my code for getting the image :

```
class ImageService {

    static let cache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()

    static func downloadImage(withURL url:URL, completion: @escaping (_ image:UIImage?)->()) {
        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, responseURL, error in
            var downloadedImage:UIImage?

            if let data = data {
                downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data)
            }

            if downloadedImage != nil {
                cache.setObject(downloadedImage!, forKey: url.absoluteString as NSString)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(downloadedImage)
            }

        }

        dataTask.resume()
    }

    static func getImage(withURL url:URL, completion: @escaping (_ image:UIImage?)->()) {
        if let image = cache.object(forKey: url.absoluteString as NSString) {
            completion(image)
        } else {
            downloadImage(withURL: url, completion: completion)
        }
    }
```

, and here is the code where I set this data:

```
func set(post:Post) {
    ImageService.getImage(withURL: post.imageid) { (image) in

        self.postimage.image = image
    }
    titlel.text = post.title
    usernamel.text = post.username
    desct.text = post.desc
}
```

, and my posts look like this when app is ran:[no good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVVip.png), and [nogood2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j3iS.jpg). also, here is a photo of my cell and they all have constraints so I don't think the problem is in this cell but [still](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT40P.png). I just want users to view Images as square normal pictures not looking tall and skinny like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use self.postimage.contentmode.scaleaspectfit

Comment: Works better. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Set the image view content mode as aspect fill and clips to bound property to true.

```
self.postimage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
self.postimage.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

In your screen shot i can see that you have not provided the height constraint, thats why the images are tall. For showing square picture just provide width and height constraint on UIImageView